# process.on('SIGINT' multiple termination signals

Tags: node.js

i have this node code that detect when Ctrl+C in pressed to that do some stuff before node app is exit

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    /* DO SOME STUFF HERE */

    process.exit()
})
```

Now this works but i would like to add to this process others terminations signals so that when Ctrl+C, Node app exits or server is restarted or shutdown or any other reason node app exits to trigger termination signal and call this process and do stuff in database before exits...

termination signals that i need to add is:

```
SIGTERM
SIGINT
SIGQUIT
SIGKILL
```

So i came to idea if is possible to do this:

```
 process.on('SIGINT', 'SIGTERM', 'SIGQUIT', 'SIGKILL', function() {
        /* DO SOME STUFF HERE */

        process.exit()
 })
```

So to pass multiple termination signals to process function..i added like this above but it does not work...how can this be done in node js?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The easiest method:

```
['SIGINT', 'SIGTERM', 'SIGQUIT']
  .forEach(signal => process.on(signal, () => {
    /** do your logic */
    process.exit();
  }));
```

Comment: Note that 'SIGKILL' cannot have a listener installed (it will throw an error immediately and terminate Node.js).  [Node.js Signal Events docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events). Changing the array to `['SIGINT', 'SIGTERM', 'SIGQUIT']` works.

Comment: while this works, it's worth noting that it would be better to define the function separately and then use the same function for each rather than creating a new arrow function for each signal. It's not really a big deal, more of a best practice -- particularly since it would allow you to unregister them if you ever needed to. that's nitpicky, though

Answer (score 32):

I'd rather go with

```js
/**
 * Do stuff and exit the process
 * @param {NodeJS.SignalsListener} signal
 */
function signalHandler(signal) {
    // do some stuff here
    process.exit()
}

process.on('SIGINT', signalHandler)
process.on('SIGTERM', signalHandler)
process.on('SIGQUIT', signalHandler)
```

for better readability instead of looping

Comment: I think the JSDoc notation should be this: `@type {NodeJS.SignalsListener}` or this `@param {NodeJS.Signals} signal` if you only want to type the argument

Answer (score 0):

```js
/**
 * 
 * @param {NodeJS.SignalsListener} signal
 */
function signalHandler(signal) {
    // your buisness logic here
    log("i xit ");
    process.exit()
}

['SIGINT', 'SIGTERM', 'SIGQUIT'].forEach(signal => process.on(signal, signalHandler));
```

Readable and cleaner version

Comment: I strongly disagree that this is readable or cleaner. If you’re going to go to the trouble of defining each of the parameters, you may as well just skip the loop altogether which adds very little. @sezanzab’s answer is better.